# How can i write a php code for getting a time and then fix it

Tags: php

i am building a blog in PHP and for every post i want to mention comments. But how can i show the comments time in PHP so that people can find out on which time the comment is being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a timestamp created_at and value set to current time stamp in your mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely going to store comments in database.

You can use mysql functions like:

```
NOW()                      CURDATE()    CURTIME()
2014-11-22 12:45:34       2014-11-22    12:45:34
```